# How to split a list into groups of 4 items in FreeMarker?

Tags: freemarker

I have an HTML list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
    <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
    <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
    <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
    <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
    <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
    <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
    <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
</ul>
```

I want to split list into groups of 4 items:

```
<ul>
    <li class="group1">
        <ul>
            <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
            <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
            <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
            <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
    <li class="group2">
        <ul>
            <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
            <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
            <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
            <li>lorem lipsum..</li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried with [**chunk**](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_chunk):

```
<ul>
    <#assign seq = nav.getChildren()>
    <#list seq?chunk(4) as row>
        <#list row as nav_child>
            <li class="${nav_class}">
                <ul>
                    <li>${nav_child.getName()}</li>
                </ul>   
            </li>
        </#list>
    </#list>
</ul>
```

It works for each `li` and not for a group of 4 `li`. So each `li` is wrapper inside `li > ul`.
How can I wrap 4 `li` inside `li > ul`?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this (the point is the placement of `#list`-s, but I have made some other changes too for better readability):

```
<ul>
    <#list nav.children?chunk(4) as navChildGroup>
        <li class="${nav_class}">
            <ul>
                <#list navChildGroup as navChild>
                    <li>${navChild.name}</li>
                </#list>
            </ul>   
        </li>
    </#list>
</ul>
```